# Полноэкранное графическое приложение в Android

Tags: android

Стоит задача написать приложение, где на главном экране в полноэкранном режиме необходимо отображать некую динамически созданную картинку (что-то вроде графика). Как это лучше сделать? Просто создать обычный полноэкранный активити в котором растянуть на весь экран ImageView и заполнять его динамически созданным Drawable? Либо же для таких надобностей применяются другие инструменты и подходы?

Comment: Как вариант SurfaceView

* http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html
* http://habrahabr.ru/post/126316/
* http://megadarja.blogspot.ru/2009/03/android-1-surface.html

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, похоже, то, что нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: А если это изображение нужно обновлять только раз в полминуты? Как думаете, имеет ли смысл использовать именно SurfaceView или же ImageView может оказаться гораздо менее ресурсозатратным? Кроме этого, необходим еще и зум щипком и перемещение с отрисовкой "за кадром".

Comment: Ну вы же сами можете  управлять потоком, который рисует, можете его подвесить на полминуты. В остальном SurfaceView это тоже view... Сам опыта работы с SurfaceView не имею, все это предположение.

Comment: Ваша правда, недоглядел. Действительно, можно достаточно тонко настроить частоту обновления, управляя зависанием потока, например, через семафор. Правда, не знаю, насколько такой подход является правильным. В любом случае, спасибо за мысль :)